# Possible to set default value for column not matched in a join?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, presto

Say I'm running a Hive query with a left outer join to pull in a new column X from table B. Instead of having null values in column X for records in table A that weren't matched, is there a way to, say, default it to a string?

Answer (score 4):

You do this using `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce(b.x, 'default value')
```

This is an ANSI standard function and is supported in Hive.

Comment: Oh, so this also works for rows that don't find a match in table B based on the ON clause? I thought the select statement wasn't even applied for rows without matches. I'll try it thanks!

Comment: @nsledeski . . . If you are using a `left join`, then all rows in the first table are "generated" by the `from` clause.